# SQL. Implicit Joins (Arrow Syntax like columnObjA->columnObjAProperty). PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, intersystems-cache

How to do this in postgresql?
http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSQL_implicitjoins

I mean this:
Using the –> operator, you can perform the same OUTER JOIN operation more succinctly:
SELECT Name, Company->Name AS CompName
FROM Sample.Employee

We want to abandon the InterSystems database, but we have many similar sql queries.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to rewrite your queries. There's no such "shortcut" in PostgreSQL (nor in any other SQL database I know of).

Comment: If you have a truly massive app that you cannot possibly modify, you might be able to do this with a PostgreSQL parser hook. You would need to get your hands dirty with the low level C code of the database or hire someone else to do so for you. It is extremely unlikely to be worth doing that instead of just adjusting your queries. Or you could put a preprocessor layer in front to translate your queries.